# Using \n in a string

Tags: mongodb, nim-lang

I'm doing a Nim project with GUI and I want to show some texts which i got from my local mongoDB.
Uplaoded some of these texts like:

> "something \nsomething \nsomething"

as a string. Made also a query (sorry for the format)

```
proc getTexts*(section : Bson) : seq[string] =
  for i in 0..<len(section["texts"]):
    result.add(section["texts"][i])
```

Then when i want to set one of these seq items as a label, or simply just echo it, looks like this:

"something \nsomething \nsomething"

not this:

"something

something

something"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you upload the text as "some\nsome" or "some\LFsome"? Maybe the DB is storing "\n" as ASCII 5C6E, when you want ASCII 0A.

Comment: "some\nsome" I used this format.

Comment: Just to be more clear: the "\n" can be one char (non-printable 0A) or two chars (backslash + n). The key here might be the upload step. How you inserted the text in the DB, and what is stored in the DB, and if the text was somehow escaped before storing. If you see "some\nsome" when you echo, i.e. you can see backslash + n, you don't have "linefeed chars" stored, but "backslash + n".

Comment: Yes, I checked the DB, and all my linefeed chars were dismissed and lost. So now uploaded the datas with double backslashes + n, and now it works.

Comment: You should write what you found as an answer to your own question and accept it. This closes the question, helps future viewers and earns you some internet points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out that I stored the new line char as 2 separate character

So, finally I made this short process

```
proc myEscape*(str: string): string =
  result = str.replace("\\n", $'\n').replace("\\t", $'\t')
```

to replace those with only one char.
Not the nicest solution, but works.